# How to check if a string has 2 consecutive items from a list?

Tags: python

I'm a python beginner and want to check if a string contains 2 consecutive items from a list.

```
a_list = operators = ['+', '-', '*', '/', '=']

a_string = '5+3=+2'
```

Code should return True if there are items from the list not adjoined, but return false if the items appear consecutively.
For example 5+3-3=2/1 should return True
5+-2=0 should return False

I can only be able to check if the item is in the string

Comment: One way to do it is by regular expression, check it out.

Comment: I'm taking a class from Georgia tech in edx, and haven't learned regular expression yet. Need to solve this using control structure and data structure only.

Comment: Please see [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 1):

Well, instead of looping over your string twice, you could just do a single for loop that checks the current index and the one ahead to check for consecutiveness. An example would be:

```
a_list = operators = ['+', '-', '*', '/', '=']
a_string = '5+3=+2'
for i in range(len(a_string)-1):  # "-1' so that your index won't go out of range
    a, b = a_string[i], a_string[i+1]
    if a in a_list and b in a_list:
        print(False)
```

Comment: This is what I needed, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate `a_list` parallely with `zip` where first list being the entire list, second list being from 2nd all the way to last, then again the first item. Then check any of `i+j` appear in the string:

```py
>>> not any(i+j in a_string for i,j in zip(a_list, a_list[1:]+[a_list[0]]))
False
```